# AWS - access the file in a folder in a s3 bucket using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to access the files in a particular s3 bucket folder (There's a folder structure).

I want to get that file as an File object in java. I have the bucket name, region name and the access id is with me.

Please let me know how to do this or a link that I can refer to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you seen this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

Comment: Yes @DavidDennis. But it has not mentioned how to get a file in a particular folder.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation to be used may be the same as the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html), however when it is necessary to read a file inside a folder, you need to specify which folder is the file.

For example, we want to get a file named **listOfCountries.json** inside the **world** folder, when you pass the key to access the S3 report folder.

```
System.out.println("Downloading an object");
fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucketName", "world/listOfCountries.json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that as a `File` object in Java since it isn't a local file. You have to download it first if you want to use the `File` class. Otherwise look at the methods available in the AWS SDK for Java.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the answer!